# Removing a pattern With gsub in r

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stringr

I have a string `Project Change Request (PCR) - HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM` saved in `supp_matches`, and `supp_matches1` contains the string `Project Change Request (PCR) -`.

```
supp_matches2 <- gsub("^.*[supp_matches1]","",supp_matches)
supp_matches2
# [1] " (PCR) - HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM"
```

Which is actually not correct but it should come like

```
supp_matches2
# [1] "HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM"
```

Why is it not coming the way it should be?

Comment: Can you add either simple assignment statemens for `supp_matches` and `supp_matches1` or a `dput` of them?

Comment: in your expression, you're asking to remove any character 0 or more times at the beginning of the string followed by one of the letters put in between the brackets (you can try to remove the object `supp_matches1` and do `gsub("^.*[supp_matches1]","",supp_matches)` you will get the exact same result.

Comment: `gsub(sprintf("^.*%s", supp_matches1), "", supp_matches)` and you also need to escape the parentheses in `supp_matches1`, but it would be better if you describe the pattern you are looking for, everything after `-`? instead of using this type of approach

Comment: supp_matches1 is a variable @rawr , in this case characters should be removed after "-" , but the string in  supp_matches1 will be changing. So i want to remove the variable string from the supp_matches.

Comment: How can i do with the dput ? @hrbrmstr , No idea of that.

Comment: now I'm not sure which string you want. you can get the pieces with ``gsub('(.*) - (.*)', '\\2', supp_matches)`` by replacing the \\2 wth \\1 to get the other or `strsplit(supp_matches, ' - ')[[1]]` to split the string into two pieces\

Comment: Thanks @rawr , But this is static for this example, supp_matches1 is a variable, and the variable pattern should be removed from the supp_matches ,How can it be done. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I say in my comment, in your expression `gsub("^.*[supp_matches1]", "", supp_matches)`, you're not really using the object `supp_matches1` but just the letters inside it.

You could do something like `gsub(paste0("^.*", supp_matches1), "", supp_matches)` to really use the expression contained in `supp_matches1`, except that, as mentionned by @rawr, you have parentheses in your expression so you would need to excape them.
The correct expression to get what you want would then be `sub("Project Change Request \\(PCR\\) - ", "", supp_matches)`

To get what you want, you can use the `fixed` parameter of `gsub` (`sub`) function, which is saying that the expression in the parameter `pattern` will be matched as it is (so, without the need to escape anything, but also, no real regular expression).

So what's you are looking for is :

```
gsub(supp_matches1, "", supp_matches, fixed=TRUE) # or just with `sub` in this case
#[1] "HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM"
```

Comment: Thanks @CathG , i got what i was looking for, Yes my code  wasn't using "supp_matches1" as a object. Now it is solved.

Answer (score 3):

Already @cathG provided an answer with fixed=TRUE. If you want to do all with regex, then you may try this.

```
> w1 <- "Project Change Request (PCR) - HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM"
> w2 <- "Project Change Request (PCR) - "
> sub(paste0("^", gsub("(\\W)", "\\\\\\1", w2)), "", w1)
[1] "HONDA DIGITAL PLATEFORM"
```

It's just a kind of escaping all the special chars present inside the variable you want to use as first parameter in sub function.