# Removing characters after a EURO symbol in R

Tags: regex, r, gsub, stringr

I have a euro symbol saved in "euro" variable:

```
euro <- "\u20AC"
euro
#[1] "€"
```

And "eurosearch" variable contains "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro" .

```
eurosearch
[1] "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro"
```

I want the characters after the Euro symbol which is "15,896.80 (if executed fro"
I am using this code:

```
gsub("^.*[euro]","",eurosearch)
```

But I'm getting empty result. How can I obtain the expected output?

Comment: Do you want `15,896.80 (if executed fro` to be output as a result? Or `15,896.80`?

Comment: I need "€ 15,896.80", but using a varible, this case its € , next time it can be $ which will be saved in 'euro' varible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in the pattern by just concatenating strings using [paste0](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html):

```
euro <- "€"
eurosearch <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro"
sub(paste0("^.*", gsub("([^A-Za-z_0-9])", "\\\\\\1", euro), "\\s*(\\S+).*"), "\\1", eurosearch)

euro <- "$"
eurosearch <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of $ 25,196.4 (if executed fro"
sub(paste0("^.*", gsub("([^A-Za-z_0-9])", "\\\\\\1", euro), "\\s*(\\S+).*"), "\\1", eurosearch)
```

See [CodingGround demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMUU1YTVJjSkV5d2c)

Note that with `gsub("([^A-Za-z_0-9])", "\\\\\\1", euro)` I am escaping any non-word symbols so that `$` could be treated as a literal, not a special regex metacharacter (taken from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221899/dynamic-regex-in-r/16222490#16222490)).

Answer (score 4):

Use regmatches present in base r or `str_extarct` in `stringr`, etc

```
> x <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro"
> regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=€ )\\S+", x, perl=T))
[1] "15,896.80"
```

**or**

```
> gsub("€ (\\S+)|.", "\\1", x)
[1] "15,896.80"
```

**or**

Using variables.

```
euro <- "\u20AC"
gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", x)
```

If this answer of using variables won't work for you then you need to set the encoding,

```
gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", `Encoding<-`(x, "UTF8"))
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31289239/3297613)

Comment: Can i use a variable in place of € in the second answer, instead of direct input of €, i want it to be variable, Assuming € is saved in some variable this time ,the next time it can be $,so !?

Comment: try `gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", x) `

Comment: The problem with `$` though, that it is a metacharacter so it will need some modification.

Comment: No @Avinash Raj ,The value is null.

Comment: `x <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro" ; euro <- "€" ; gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", x)` works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, 
`x <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of $ 15,896.80 (if executed fro"`
`euro <- "$"`
`gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", `Encoding<-`(x, "UTF8"))`
[1] ""
so I'm getting Null value

Comment: @Shivpe_R i didn't find any `$` symbol on your input. Since `$` is a special char, you must escape it. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31268302/3297613 to your previous question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj , Okay now I'm able to do with the $ sign too as keeping in [$] and escape it as a spec char, Got it , Thanks