# Confused with the locale settings in R

Tags: regex, r

Just now I answered this [Removing characters after a EURO symbol in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288513/removing-characters-after-a-euro-symbol-in-r) question. But it's not working for me where the r code works for others who are on Ubuntu.

This is my code.

```
x <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro"
euro <- "\u20AC"
gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", x)
# ""
```

I think this is all about changing the locale settings, I don't know how to do that.

I'm running rstudio on Windows 8.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.0
```

@Anada's answer is good but we need to add that `encoding` parameter for every time when we use unicodes in regex. Is there any way to modify the default encoding to `utf-8` on Windows?

Comment: "If you don't set a default encoding, files will be opened using UTF-8 (on Mac desktop, Linux desktop, and server) or the system's default encoding (on Windows)" (from [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding)).

Comment: You can set the default encoding using `options(encoding = "UTF-8")`.  This isn't the magic solution you want it to be though.  UTF-8 support in R on Windows isn't great; I half-remember a conversation about it needing lots of conversions to and from UTF-16 which broke things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with encoding.

Consider:

```
x <- "services as defined in this SOW at a price of € 15,896.80 (if executed fro"
gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", x)
# [1] ""
gsub(paste(euro , "(\\S+)|."), "\\1", `Encoding<-`(x, "UTF8"))
# [1] "15,896.80"
```