# Matching curly quotation marks in R

Tags: regex, r

I'm having a problem matching curly quotation marks, in UTF-8 encoded text (novels, downloaded from Project Gutenberg). I have no trouble matching novels in which quotations are enclosed by a straight apostrophe ('), but when quotations come enclosed in curly quotation marks, I can't seem to find them. I tried to find the integer-equivalent using `utf8ToInt()`, but it returned `NA` for the curly marks.

I searched around but couldn't find anyone with this problem in R. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
hardtimes<-readLines(con="http://www.gutenberg.org/files/786/786-0.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
tmp<-hardtimes[368] #sample line with quotes in it
str_detect(tmp,"‘") #returns FALSE
str_count(tmp,"‘") #returns 0
utf8ToInt("‘") #returns NA
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31289239/3297613

Comment: It works for me. Are you by any chance on Windows?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah, I am. It must be that, I suppose. The workaround below is good enough for my purposes, but what are the deeper reasons this doesn't work?

Comment: @daanoo Unicode support for R is broken on Windows. It *may* help to explicitly save your source file as UTF-8, and loading it in R via `eval(parse(file, encoding='UTF-8'))` instead of via `source`. Another idea is to explicitly assign an encoding to a string variable containing the apostrophe. But I don't know if either would actually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of cheating: Might be a Windows problem. Tested on Windows.

```
library(stringr)
hardtimes <-
  readLines(con = "http://www.gutenberg.org/files/786/786-0.txt",encoding =
              "UTF-8")
tmp <- hardtimes[368] #sample line with quotes in it
tmp 
backtickInt <- utf8ToInt(tmp)[1]
backtick <- intToUtf8(backtickInt)

str_detect(tmp,backtick) #returns FALSE
str_count(tmp, backtick) #returns 0
utf8ToInt("‘") #returns NA
```