# R gsub & regex find price

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I am trying to create a new vector of prices from the given text. I am only allowed to use `gsub`.

```
test = c('Testing $26,500\ntesting', 
         'Testing tesing $79+\n TOTAL: $79200', 
         'Testing $3880. Testing', 
         'Testing -$69000Engine: $69000100%',
         'Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5')
```

**Desired Output:**

```
# [1] 26500 79200  3880 69000  7495
```

I have tried multiple regular expressions but I can't get the correct results.

First attempt:

```
gsub(".*\\$(\\d+)[,|.](\\d+).*", "\\1\\2", test)
# [1] "26500"                                                               
# [2] "Testing tesing $79+\n TOTAL: $79200"                                 
# [3] "Testing $3880. Testing"                                              
# [4] "Testing -$69000Engine: $69000100%"                                   
# [5] "Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5"
```

Second attempt:

```
gsub(".*\\$(\\d+)[,|.].*", "\\1", test) 
# [1] "26"                                                                  
# [2] "Testing tesing $79+\n TOTAL: $79200"                                 
# [3] "3880"                                                                
# [4] "Testing -$69000Engine: $69000100%"                                   
# [5] "Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5"
```

Third attempt:

```
gsub("(?:.*|.*?*)\\$([0-9]+).*", "\\1", test) 
# [1] "26"                                                                  
# [2] "79200"                                                               
# [3] "3880"                                                                
# [4] "69000100"                                                            
# [5] "Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5"
```

Fourth attempt:

```
gsub(".*[-]\\$(\\d+).*", "\\1", test) 
# [1] "Testing $26,500\ntesting"                                            
# [2] "Testing tesing $79+\n TOTAL: $79200"                                 
# [3] "Testing $3880. Testing"                                              
# [4] "69000"                                                               
# [5] "Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5"
```

**Question**: How can I fix this and avoid using multiple `gsub` function calls?

Comment: @akrun: No, it's not the homework. I have read this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31288513/removing-characters-after-a-euro-symbol-in-r) . And I try to come up with some more examples to test it out. Since I'm learning regex in R so I did not want to try it with the package stringr.

Comment: You know you could just copy/paste the console instead of all those pics.  Easier on both you and us.

Comment: @Richard Scriven : I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I'm just getting used  stackoverflow recently. However, only the result is the screenshot, all the code are in the code block.

Comment: How about using `gsubfn` and passing proto object to `gsub`, would that be allowed? You could pass digits + punctuation and later take the digits after the `$` sign. The one price with `100%` at the end confuses me a little. I'm guessing that `100%` is redundant?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a way to use only 1 call to `gsub` as you need to pre-process the last price where digits are "disconnected" with spaces, and the first one with a comma decimal separator.

I can only "contract" the code to 2 gsub calls:

- `gsub("([$]|(?!^)\\G)[\\s,]*(\\d)", "\\1\\2", test, perl=T)` will remove commas and spaces between the digits that follow `$` symbol
- `gsub("^(?|[\\s\\S]*-[$](\\d+)|[\\s\\S]*[$](\\d+))[\\s\\S]*$", "\\1", test, perl=T)` will actually get the required price number out of the strings.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/WVd4rI):

```
test <- c("Testing $26,500\ntesting","Testing tesing $79+\n TOTAL: $79200","Testing $3880. Testing", "Testing -$69000Engine: $69000100%","Testing testing original price : $ 8 2 9 5 . Real price is $ 7 4 9 5")
test <- gsub("([$]|(?!^)\\G)[\\s,]*(\\d)", "\\1\\2", test, perl=T)
test <- gsub("^(?|[\\s\\S]*-[$](\\d+)|[\\s\\S]*[$](\\d+))[\\s\\S]*$", "\\1", test, perl=T)
test
```

Result: `[1] "26500" "79200" "3880"  "69000" "7495"`

Since you are learning regex, here are regex breakdowns:

***Regex 1:***

- `([$]|(?!^)\\G)` - match and *capture* a "leading boundary" construct matching a `$` symbol and the location after each successful match with `(?!^)\G` (`\G` also matches the beginning of a string, and we eliminate it with a negative look-ahead `(?!^)`)
- `[\\s,]*` - match 0 or more commas or whitespace
- `(\\d)` - match and *capture* a digit

With `\1\2` replacement pattern, we restore the `$` symbol and the digits after it inside the string.

***Regex 2:***

- `^` - Beginning of a string
- `(?|[\\s\\S]*-[$](\\d+)|[\\s\\S]*[$](\\d+))` - a *branch-reset group* (`(?|...|...)`) where capturing group index is reset to 1 (so, we only need to use `\1` reference in the replacement pattern to address both `(\\d+)`  from each alternative) matching....

  - `[\\s\\S]*-[$](\\d+)` - any zero or more characters (`[\s\S]*`) followed with a hyphen, then a `$`, and then 1 or more digits (`\d+`, Group 1)
  - `|` - or...
  - `[\\s\\S]*[$](\\d+)`  - any zero or more characters (`[\s\S]*`) followed with a `$` and then 1 or more digits (`\d+`, **still Group 1**)

And we replace all with just `\1` back-reference to get our results.
 - `[\\s\\S]*$` - any characters, 0 or more occurrences (`[\s\S]*`), up to the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. I'm reading sequence define but could not find out what \\G means in your Regex 1.

Comment: I have described `\G` as *the location after each successful match* and *the beginning of a string*. Since we do not want to match at the beginning  of a string, we add a negative look-ahead `(?!^)`.